# Netlogo: How to make a turtle check for variables in a radius

Tags: netlogo, patch

I want the turtles to check in a radius of 2 if the temperature of a patch is within the acceptable range that the turtle have, if it is then he would move there, if not then get out of the patch/dont go there.  Any guidance will be appreciated and if any more info is needed please let me know.

Ive seen some questiones here but they seem to complex and i dont fully understand.

Thanks.

```
turtles-own [energia]
;La tierra tiene tres estados, borde abandono y bosque. Cada estado tiene sus valores de temperatura, humedad relativa y dosel 
patches-own  
[bordear
abandono
reforestado
potrerizado
temperatura
humedad
dosel
]
breed [ potreros potrero ] 
to setup
  clear-all
;Se segmenta el mundo en potrero, borde y bosque. Se ponen colores para diferenciarlos 
  ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 30 and
    pxcor >= min-pxcor and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 35
    set temperatura 28
  ]
 create-potreros 50

  [ set size 3        ;; easier to see
    set color yellow
setxy random xcor random ycor
move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 35]
    set energia 100
 ] 
end
to go
  ask potreros [
    ;if energia < 10 [descansar-potrero]
    if energia >= 10 and energia <= 70 [move-potrero]]
end
to move-potrero
    ask turtles in-radius 2 [if temperatura >= 27 + random  1 [ 
      lt random-float 360
      fd 1]  
  ]
   set energia energia - 5

end
´´´
This is most of the code, the turtle arent moving.
```

Comment: Since you want to check the temperature of a patch, then the patches need a variable (patches-own) to store their temperature. But it sounds like you are missing some basic concepts and need to start from something simpler than this question. There are some excellent tutorials at the NetLogo site, and have a look at some of the models in the model library.

Comment: @JenB , thanks for answering. Ive seen some examples using myself but looking at the definition in the netlogo dictionary i dont have it clear. Do you think that one is useful in my case?

Comment: @JenB , I added some code and it seems that the patches have their temperature but the turtles arent moving. I think im on the right track let me know please

Comment: The beetles don't move, because their `energia` is 100. You ask the turtles to move, if their `energia` is smaller than 70. 
When you correct that, you will run into another error, because you `ask patches (...) lt random-float 360 fd 1` and patches can't left-turn nor move forward. What you want to do is to ask the beetle to move to one of the surrounding patches that have an acceptable temperature, I guess. You don't want the patches to do anything there.

Comment: @Lena Thanks for the correction! what you said is exactly what i whant to do, if the turtle is within close to a "good" temperature, fo there. how would you suggest i do that? I got the error you predicte.

Comment: @Lena, I corrected the move command and now the turtles move! but im not sure that it is for the right reason, as when they reach a point of not-good temperature they dont turn around

Answer (score 2):

Here are the proper steps to debug: 
-start with 1 turtle 
-in the Gui, create watch/plots for the variables you are debugging. for example, plot the energy of turtle 0 to see where this is going wrong.
-once you have that bug figured out, have a look at the `with` keyword and the `agentset` documentation. instead of using the `ask` keyword, you can create an agentset of patches with sufficient temperature using `with` and choose one of them with `one-of` and move there.